# Add extra headers in feathers socket from feathers client

Tags: websocket, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a feathers client in reactjs which uses mostly socket connections which is inturn integrated into an iframe. I am supposed to send the parent url from feathers client to my backend.

for instance, my feathers client is running on abc.com , and xyz.com is integrating abc.com in an iframe. I am supposed to get xyz.com in feathers socket object or pass the parent domain as extra headers to my feathers server.

Answer (score 2):

Extra headers can be passed when initializing the [Socket.io client](https://socket.io/docs/client-api) through the [`extraHeaders` options](https://socket.io/docs/client-api):

```
const socket = io({
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        'x-clientid': 'abc'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am familiar with accessing headers on server side with the below code snippet

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    Object.assign(socket.feathers, {headers: socket.handshake.headers});
    socket.feathers.ip = socket.conn.remoteAddress;
  });

But how do i access the extra headers, on the server side.

Comment: Also, When i was searching on the internet , I came across the below code 

const socket = io('http://192.168.32.126:3030',{
  transports: ['polling', 'websocket'], // or simply omit since this is the default
  // Send the authorization header in the initial connection request
  polling: {
    extraHeaders: {
      urlKing: 'king of queens'
    }
  }
});

The solution which you suggested and the above are one and the same, or are they different.

Comment: It's the same and it will just be added to the headers you receive on the server side.

Comment: Probaly i might be missing something.
client code:
const socket = io('http://localhost:3030',{
    websocket: {
      extraHeaders: {
        'extraone': 'extraheading'
      }
    }
});
server side:
app.configure(socketio(function (io) {
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.handshake.headers);
    Object.assign(socket.feathers, {headers: socket.handshake.headers});
    socket.feathers.ip = socket.conn.remoteAddress;
  });
Am not getting the extra headers i set in the logs nor in the headers. Please help me out
}));

Comment: Also tried replacing "websocket" with "polling" on client side as you mentioned. Still no difference

Comment: I came across this line on the internet 
"With extraHeaders

This only works if polling transport is enabled (which is the default). Custom headers will not be appended when using websocket as the transport. This happens because the WebSocket handshake does not honor custom headers."